# How do I add all the filenames from a specific folder to my list?

Tags: android, listview

So basically I have a folder called "saved_images", where I have a bunch of images. I want to be able to get all the filenames from that folder and add it to a list I have. For example, if I had "picture1.jpg" and "picture2.jpg" in this folder, I want my list to show up as "picture1", "picture2". How can I accomplish this? Below is my code for the Listview, any help would be much appreciated.

```
 public class List extends MainActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    String[] foods = {stringLabel};
    ListAdapter buckysAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);
    ListView buckysListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    buckysListView.setAdapter(buckysAdapter);

    buckysListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String food = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(List.this, food, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get all the files inside the folder inside using the *`getFilesName()`*
pass folder path as parameter to it. and set the string[] to your `ListAdapter`

```
String[] fileNames = getFilesName(*FolderPath*);
if(fileNames!=null)
ListAdapter buckysAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fileNames);
```

use this function to get all files list

```
   private String[] getFilesName(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists()||!file.isDirectory())return null;
    return file.list();
   }
```

**Note : Not Tested**